# does hive allows column name as "rows"?

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, hive-serde

I know every hive version has some reserve keywords, which cant be used as a column name.

But the problem is my data comes from a json, and my column name are according to the json values.

And I cant modify the data off course.
Is there any alternative??

here is one row of the sample data and the table.

```
{"id" : "eew7-9yf2", "name" : "Student Loan Complaints", "averageRating" : 0, "createdAt" : 1434385453, "description" : "Each week we send thousands of consumers' complaints about financial products and services to companies for response. Complaints are listed in the database after the company responds or after theyâ€™ve had the complaint for 15 calendar days, whichever comes first.<br><br>\r\n\r\nWe publish the consumerâ€™s description of what happened if the consumer opts to share it and after taking steps to remove personal information. See our <a href=\"http://files.consumerfinance.gov/a/assets/201503_cfpb_Narrative-Scrubbing-Standard.pdf\">Scrubbing Standard</a> for more details<br><br>\r\n\r\nWe donâ€™t verify all the facts alleged in these complaints, but we take steps to confirm a commercial relationship. We may remove complaints if they donâ€™t meet all of the publication criteria. Data is refreshed nightly.<br><br>\r\n\r\n<a href=\"http://www.consumerfinance.gov/complaintdatabase/\">More about the Consumer Complaint Database</a> | <a href=\"http://www.consumerfinance.gov/complaint/data-use/\">How we use complaint data</a> | <a href=\"http://www.consumerfinance.gov/complaintdatabase/technical-documentation/\">Technical documentation</a>", "displayType" : "table", "downloadCount" : 1461, "hideFromCatalog" : false, "hideFromDataJson" : false, "indexUpdatedAt" : 1520460881, "moderationStatus" : true, "modifyingViewUid" : "s6ew-h6mp", "newBackend" : false, "numberOfComments" : 0, "oid" : 22199210, "provenance" : "official", "publicationAppendEnabled" : false, "publicationDate" : 1467818298, "publicationGroup" : 2819740, "publicationStage" : "published", "rowsUpdatedAt" : 1520454464, "rowsUpdatedBy" : "pjxg-ve4m", "tableId" : 11756201, "totalTimesRated" : 0, "viewCount" : 4630, "viewLastModified" : 1456271502, "viewType" : "tabular", "grants" : [ {  "inherited" : true, "type" : "viewer", "flags" : [ "public" ]} ], "metadata" : {  "rdfSubject" : "0", "richRendererConfigs" : {    "fatRow" : {      "columns" : [{"styles" : {"width" : "27%"        },        "rows" : [ {"fields" : [ { "tableColumnId" : 28249505, "type" : "columnLabel"}, { "tableColumnId" : 28249505, "type" : "columnData"} ]},{"fields" : [ { "tableColumnId" : 28249497, "type" : "columnLabel"}, { "tableColumnId" : 28249497, "type" : "columnData"} ]},{"fields" : [ { "tableColumnId" : 28249498, "type" : "columnLabel"}, { "tableColumnId" : 28249498, "type" : "columnData"} ]},{"fields" : [ { "tableColumnId" : 28249499, "type" : "columnLabel"}, { "tableColumnId" : 28249499, "type" : "columnData"} ]},{"fields" : [ { "tableColumnId" : 28249500, "type" : "columnLabel"}, { "tableColumnId" : 28249500, "type" : "columnData"} ]},{"fields" : [ { "tableColumnId" : 28249502, "type" : "columnLabel"}, { "tableColumnId" : 28249502, "type" : "columnData"} ]},{"fields" : [ { "tableColumnId" : 28249503, "type" : "columnLabel"}, { "tableColumnId" : 28249503, "type" : "columnData"} ]},{"fields" : [ { "tableColumnId" : 28249504, "type" : "columnLabel"}, { "tableColumnId" : 28249504, "type" : "columnData"}] }]}, {        "styles" : {"width" : "40%"        },        "rows" : [ {"fields" : [ { "tableColumnId" : 28249493, "type" : "columnLabel"}, { "tableColumnId" : 28249493, "type" : "columnData"} ]},{"fields" : [ { "tableColumnId" : 28249495, "type" : "columnLabel"}, { "tableColumnId" : 28249495, "type" : "columnData"}] }]}, {        "styles" : {"width" : "30%"        },        "rows" : [ {"fields" : [ { "tableColumnId" : 28249508, "type" : "columnLabel"}, { "tableColumnId" : 28249508, "type" : "columnData"} ]},{"fields" : [ { "tableColumnId" : 28249507, "type" : "columnLabel"}, { "tableColumnId" : 28249507, "type" : "columnData"} ]},{"fields" : [ { "tableColumnId" : 28249509, "type" : "columnLabel"}, { "tableColumnId" : 28249509, "type" : "columnData"} ]},{"fields" : [ { "tableColumnId" : 28249510, "type" : "columnLabel"}, { "tableColumnId" : 28249510, "type" : "columnData"} ]},{"fields" : [ { "tableColumnId" : 28249511, "type" : "columnLabel"}, { "tableColumnId" : 28249511, "type" : "columnData"} ]},{"fields" : [ { "tableColumnId" : 28249492, "type" : "columnLabel"}, { "tableColumnId" : 28249492, "type" : "columnData"}] }]      } ]    }  }, "availableDisplayTypes" : [ "table", "fatrow", "page" ], "renderTypeConfig" : {    "visible" : {      "table" : true    }  }}, "owner" : {  "id" : "dfzt-mv86", "displayName" : "CFPB Administrator", "screenName" : "CFPB Administrator", "type" : "interactive", "flags" : [ "organizationMember" ]}},, "rights" : [ "read" ], "tableAuthor" : {  "id" : "pjxg-ve4m", "displayName" : "Shannon Files", "screenName" : "Shannon Files", "type" : "interactive", "flags" : [ "organizationMember" ]}},





create table complex5 (
id STRING,
name STRING,
averageRating FLOAT,
createdAt FLOAT,
description STRING,
displayType STRING,
downloadCount INT,
hideFromCatalog BOOLEAN,
hideFromDataJson BOOLEAN,
indexUpdatedAt FLOAT,
moderationStatus BOOLEAN,
newBackend BOOLEAN,
numberOfComments INT,
oid INT,
provenance STRING,
publicationAppendEnabled BOOLEAN,
publicationDate FLOAT,
publicationGroup INT,
publicationStage STRING,
rowClass STRING,
rowsUpdatedAt FLOAT,
rowsUpdatedBy STRING,
tableId INT,
totalTimesRated INT,
viewCount INT,
viewLastModified FLOAT,
viewType STRING,
grants ARRAY<MAP<STRING, STRING>>,
metadata STRUCT<rdfSubject:STRING, richRendererConfigs:STRUCT<fatRow:STRUCT<columns:ARRAY<STRUCT<styles:MAP<STRING,STRING>,rows:ARRAY<MAP<STRING,ARRAY<STRUCT<tableColumnId:INT,type:String>>>>>>>> , rowLabel:STRING, availableDisplayTypes: ARRAY<STRING>, renderTypeConfig:MAP<STRING, MAP<STRING, BOOLEAN>>>,
owner STRUCT<id:STRING, displayName:STRING, screenName:STRING, type:STRING, flags:ARRAY<STRING>>,
rights ARRAY<STRING>,
tableAuthor MAP<STRING, STRING>
)ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ROWS` is a reserved word](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Keywords,Non-reservedKeywordsandReservedKeywords)

You can always escape reserved words

```
`rows`:ARRAY
```

Alternatively [add a different SerDe that allows field renaming](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde#mapping-hive-keywords)

Answer (score 1):

There was a [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6013), which was fixed in `Hive 0.13.0` version.
As per the release

> The default behavior for quoted identifiers has been changed. Now at
>   the language level any Column Name that is specified within
>   back-ticks(`) is treated literally. This is inline with standard sql
>   behavior for quoted identifiers. Within back-tick strings use double
>   back-ticks to escape.

**Enabling Quoted Identifiers**

Set the `hive.support.quoted.identifiers` configuration parameter to `column` in the `hive-site.xml` file to enable quoted identifiers in SQL column names. For `Hive 0.13`, the valid values are `none` and `column`.

```
set hive.support.quoted.identifiers = column
```

e.g.

In the following example, `x+y` and `a?b` are valid column names for a new table.

```
CREATE TABLE test (`x+y` String, `a?b` String);
```